# Foundation 6 custom color palette doesn't work

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

i'm trying to change the color palette ($foundation-palette) just like the guide from the Global Styles on Zurb Foundation, placing it on base/settings.scss file, but it doesn't seems to be working. here is the code:

```
// settings.scss
$foundation-palette: (
  primary: #FF7212,
  secondary: #000000,
  success: #3adb76,
  warning: #ffae00,
  alert: #cc4b37,
);

// app.scss
@import 'base/mixins';
@import 'base/variables';
@import 'base/settings';
@import 'base/color';
@import 'base/reset';
@import 'base/global';
@import 'base/text';
```

Any help, please, thanks...

Comment: what do you mean by it doesn't seems to be working? Shows false colors? Is there an error? What do you get when you do a `map-get()`?

Answer (score 1):

All the variables from this Sass map are already defined and are/can be used by calling on a CSS property like:

```
.thing {
  color: $success-color;
}
```

You can add your own map key value pairs like here I added a tertiary key:

```
$foundation-palette: (
  primary: #5C27AF,
  secondary: #3adb76,
  tertiary: #009CBF,
  success: #3adb76,
  warning: #ffae00,
  error: #cc4b37,
  alert: #E3162F,
);
```

To call this new map key and get the value:

```
.thing {
  color: get-color(tertiary);
}
```